# Is there a way to stack images side by side with imagemagick?

Tags: command-line, imagemagick, image-processing

I'm writing a little program in C/C++ to convert gifs to a single image, where the frames are consecutive in a single image. Unfortunately, I am running out of free time, and I want to use the program sooner than I might be done with it. So I am wondering, is this functionality existent in imagemagick?

Can I take a set of images and convert them to one image? Not like an animated gif, but like a series of frames within one image.

Comment: The relevant `imagemagick` tool would be [montage](http://www.imagemagick.org/Usage/montage/) I think

Comment: I'll check it out, I just came across append, which stacks the images vertically.

Comment: montage almost works, but after 12 images, it starts a new line. I need to keep all the frames on one line. how do I do that?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

ok i figured it out. 
you can do this:
$`convert a.gif a.png`
this will give you a series of images a-1.png, a-2.png, a-n.png .... and so on. 
then, you can do this:
`convert +append a-*.png out.png`

This will give you a horizontal sprite sheet instead of a vertical one, in out.png.  A single line of code my be possible, I have like 0 extra time to figure it out though.